# Android Studio 1.5 - How to display javadoc for google play services in AS

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Currently, I am using google play services for my project. Everything works fine, but if I open the javadoc for e.g. the GoogleApiClient it only displays the method signature and no further documentation.

It is possible to display those documentations in Android Studio 1.5 for e.g. google play services?

If so, what settings need to be done?

Comment: I think like `GoogleApiClient` class, it not a part of Android native SDK, so it omit the document for that. I have the workaround, install `android-sdk search` google chrome extension, and input `ad` then press `TAB` key. Search the class. It's quick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Right click in **Project panel**  > **External libraries** > **lib-name**
2. Click **Library properties**
   [image: Lib props]
3. Click specify documentation URL
4. And specify an URL. For my machine it was `file:///opt/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference` or as @Benjamin suggested in the comments, add `http://developer.android.com/reference/` as source, for online documentation lookup.
   [image: Add doc url]
5. The result was:
   [image: added jdoc]
6. And after a project sync I could browse the javadoc of the **google play services**
   [image: google play services maps javadoc]

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. One addition, instead of needing to lookup the correct location on your computer, the following URL can be used instead: `http://developer.android.com/reference/`

Comment: A small addition. If you installed sdk via Android Studio you can just to add  
`file://$USER_HOME$/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference` (note using of `$USER_HOME$`). **This is an example for play services package docs**